# Array to OpenCV matrix

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a array `double dc[][]` and want to convert this as to a `IplImage* image` and further to a video frame.
What I had to do was I was given a video and I extracted out some features and then make a new video of the extracted features.
My approach was I divided the video into frames extracted the features from each frame then did the updation like this and in each iteration of frame I get a new dc

```
double dc[48][44];
for(int i=0;i<48;i++)
{
  for(int j=0;j<44;j++)
  {
     dc[i][j]=max1[i][j]/(1+max2[i][j]);
  }
}
```

Now I need to save this dc in such a way that I can reconstruct the video.Anybody help me with this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're using the C++ opencv interface why not use Mat instead of IplImage?

Comment: I am fine with using Mat as well but I have not been able to convert this double to Mat and furthermore when saving into video I only know how to save a lpllmage and not Mat.

Answer (score 1):

If you're okay with using `Mat`, then you can make a `Mat` for existing user-allocated memory. One of the `Mat` constructors has the signature:

```
Mat::Mat(int rows, int cols, int type, void* data, size_t step=AUTO_STEP)
```

where the parameters are:

```
rows: the memory height, 
cols: the width, 
type: one of the OpenCV data types (e.g. CV_8UC3), 
data: pointer to your data, 
step: (optional) stride of your data
```

I'd encourage you to take a look at the documentation for `Mat` [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat)

EDIT: Just to make things more concrete, here's an example of making a Mat from some user-allocated data

```
int main()
{
    //allocate and initialize your user-allocated memory
    const int nrows = 10;
    const int ncols = 10;
    double data[nrows][ncols];
    int vals = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < ncols; j++)
        {
            data[i][j] = vals++;
        }
    }
    //make the Mat from the data (with default stride)
    cv::Mat cv_data(nrows, ncols, CV_64FC1, data);
    //print the Mat to see for yourself
    std::cout << cv_data << std::endl;
}
```

You can save a Mat to a video file via the OpenCV [VideoWriter class](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html). You just need to create a VideoWriter, open a video file, and write your frames (as Mat). You can see an example of using [VideoWriter here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.5/doc/tutorials/highgui/video-write/video-write.html)

Here's a short example of using the VideoWriter class:

```
//fill-in a name for your video 
const std::string filename = "...";
const double FPS = 30;
VideoWriter outputVideo;
//opens the output video file using an MPEG-1 codec, 30 frames per second, of size height x width and in color 
outputVideo.open(filename, CV_FOURCC('P','I','M,'1'), FPS, Size(height, width));

Mat frame;
//do things with the frame
// ...

//writes the frame out to the video file
outputVideo.write(frame);
```

The tricky part of the VideoWriter is the opening of the file, as you have a lot of options. You can see the names for [different codecs here](http://www.fourcc.org/codecs.php)

Comment: Actually the problem is I have a video I need to take out RBG do some feature extraction and make a video back of extracted features.
Now can u help if I have obtained this cv::Mat how can Use this to form a image or a video.

Comment: @0908 I added in some code to my answer for using VideoWriter. I'd really advise for you to read the documentation for the class though (as well as the sample application), as there are a lot of parameters that will be specific to your application. Links to those are in the answer

Comment: once you've created and opened your `VideoWriter` object (e.g. if it's named out_vid, then you just do out_vid.write(cv_data);). Writing the Mat out to the video is the easy part, the hard(er) part is opening the video file

Comment: Use the `isOpened()` member function of VideoWriter to check if it opened correctly prior to writing. e.g. `if(!out_vid.isOpened()) std::cerr << "File Not Opened" << std::endl;`

Comment: OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (image->depth == 8) in unknown function, file ..\
..\..\modules\highgui\src\cap_ffmpeg.cpp, line 230

Comment: @0908 That error means that you're mis-matching Mat types, e.g. using a Mat allocated as having 8-bit elements when it's actually something else. But this is pretty basic stuff, you might want to get familiar with the fundamentals of OpenCV before trying to too extensive of a project with it

Comment: Actually I am shifting from matlab and hence facing these problem and me working on improving the fundamentals as It is quite difficult for me. Underneath is the link of the code I am doing and the error I am getting 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576525/asertion-error-in-opencv)
Thanks so much your time to help me on this